# Resize before switching place?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple setup like this :

```
<div id="div0">
 <div id="div1">Content</div>
 <div id="div2">Content</div>
</div>
```

The two middle divs(1,2) have width:100% and max-width:390px plus floatLeft. When resizing the browser div2 will jump a row down and when getting less then width 390 thay will both start to resize.

What I need is to resize to a min-width first and then jump down to the second line.

How do I do that?

Edit1 : example : http://jsfiddle.net/dwDZx/

Comment: What 3rd div?  Can you jsfiddle an example?

Comment: your question still makes no sense. there is no 3rd div unless you are referring to the outer div. you need to clarify a bit more the intention.

Comment: Your jsfiddle contains no min width, only max-width.  What do you expect to happen?  If max width is 390, you want it to first scale down to 300 before jumping down a line, for example?

Comment: Yes, I need it to first scale down to a specific width(not set) and when it need to be smaller it simple jumps down a row.

Comment: i think you are talking about a responsive layout? something like: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. can you clarify? the css file specifies certain width "stop points". When a width is within a certain amount it will do something specific to the content on the page.

Comment: @JaredEitnier +1.  I agree, you'll likely want a responsive design.  I'll update a very basic version on jsfiddle to show how it'd be done.

Comment: Yes, its a responsive layout I try to create. What I need is simple. In full size the webpage will look regular but when I resize browser width(or use a smaller unit) the with of the elements should be resized as well(smaller). In this case I also need div2 to jump down to second row when it can´t be any smaller(say 200px width).

Comment: @Ivy Before I do anything, have you looked at bootstrap?  Bootstrap does exactly this.  In particular, look at its fluid grid examples.

Comment: @Ivy, It would be very beneficial for you (although this request is simple in nature) to learn the basics of responsive design by playing with some pre-generated files. The best place to start is http://www.initializr.com/. This is where I started and it was a huge help. You can start with a basic layout and remove elements you don't need to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a responsive example of what you're asking about. I  changed some widths to make it easier to follow the example and see where the numbers come from.  http://jsfiddle.net/dwDZx/4/

I change background colors in the different responsive layouts to show you which section is active at which point in resizing the browser.

The only change I made to the markup was to create a "content" div inside div1 and div2.  This allowed me to set a border.  If I set width of div1 and div2 to 50% *AND* set a border, then the total width would be 50%+2px (1px left + 1px right) which would cause the floats to wrap.  By putting the border on the content div, it puts the borders *inside* the 50% instead of outside.

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.content { border: 1px solid black; }

#div1, #div2
{
        float:left;
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    #div1, #div2
    {
        width:          400px;
        background: green;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    #div1, #div2
    {
        width: 49.9%;
    background: red;
    }        
}

@media (max-width: 399px)
{
    #div1, #div2
    {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I thought about it and simplified things a bit.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dwDZx/5/  The CSS changes as follows: set a max-width on the parent div to be the max width of div1+div2.  Then you only need one media state: for when it's < 400px and should be on one line.

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.content { border: 1px solid black; }
#container { max-width: 800px; }

#div1, #div2
{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    #div1, #div2
    {
        background: red;
    }        
}

@media (max-width: 399px)
{
    #div1, #div2
    {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ivy, This is probably a good place to start for you. You will need to just dive into Eli's example and experiment. It will do what you need though.